# Unknown FileAttributes

Tags: windows, file-attributes

I tried to run the following code:

```
var top = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\");
foreach(var info in top.GetFileSystemInfos())
    System.Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", info.Name, info.Attributes);
```

I got the following result:

> $Recycle.Bin: Hidden, System, Directory
>   ATI: Directory
>   Documents and Settings: Hidden, System, Directory, **ReparsePoint**, **NotContentIndexed**
>   MSOCache: ReadOnly, Hidden, Directory, NotContentIndexed
>   PerfLogs: Directory
>   Program Files: ReadOnly, Directory
>   Program Files (x86): **65553**
>   ProgramData: **73746**
>   Recovery: Hidden, System, Directory, NotContentIndexed
>   System Volume Information: Hidden, System, Directory
>   Users: ReadOnly, Directory
>   Windows: **65552**
>   hiberfil.sys: Hidden, System, Archive, NotContentIndexed
>   pagefile.sys: Hidden, System, Archive

Most of those are pretty obvious. But what does those marked in bold mean? Especially the numeric ones for Program Files and Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes of FileSystemInfo are taken from [`FileAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes%28VS.71%29.aspx), which is an enumeration.

- The numbers correspond to the sum of adding the various bits together.
- **ReparsePoint** means that there's a reparse point on this directory, which causes NTFS to look at some special data that's been stored along with the directory. You can read more about how they work **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365503%28VS.85%29.aspx)**.
- **NotContentIndexed** means that if there's a content-indexing service running, it won't look at this directory.

Answer (score 2):

I think, this is a sum of attributes from [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332330%28VS.85%29.aspx)

For example,

```
65552 = 65536 (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_VIRTUAL) + 16 (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
```

and so on.